# как заставить код повторяться после окончания

Tags: python

Есть такой код

```
import webbrowser
import time

webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=.&clid=2411726&lr=62', new=2)
pyautogui.click(1297, 42, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1215, 180, duration = 0.2)
pyautogui.click(1124, 363, duration = 0.2)
 
time.sleep(5)
 
webbrowser.open(s, new=2)
 
time.sleep(2)
```

как заставить его повторяться после окончания кода , заранее спасибо

Comment: А что такое `s`, эта переменная нигде не присваивается, но используется?

Comment: это маленькая часть кода где я обрезал почти все , мне нужно чтобы вы просто показали как этот код зациклить , а потом уже я по вашему примеру напишу это на большом коде

Comment: А, я уже видел другой ваш видимо вопрос, где из `input` эта переменная берётся

Comment: я создал новый вопрос где все подробно описал

Answer (score 0):

В конце добавь

```
import os, sys
os.execv(sys.executable, sys.args)
```